# Excel XY chart coordinates for data labels loop through multiple chart template

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone help me adjust the following code to loop through the range of datapoints for two data series? Also help me to loop through multiple charts on different sheets in the same workbook? Also is there a way to asign the incremetal `.Left = XVal` to a a calculated cell so that this adjusts automatically depending on axis/ number of data points displayed?

This is for an XY chart - I came across the code [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/337847-vba-accessing-coordinates-data-series-chart.html) and it gets the coordinates of a data point and positions the datalabels above the data series. I have two data series on each chart that I need to use this for - SeriesCollection 5 and SeriesCollection 3. I have used an incremental `.Left = XVal` incremental value so that the data labels position sequentially at the top of the chart.

```
Public Sub ChangeCoordinates()
    Dim cht As Excel.Chart
    Dim srs As Excel.Series

    Dim i As Long

    Set cht = Application.ActiveChart
    Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(5)

    For i = 1 To srs.Points.Count
        XVal = ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.CHART.ITEM(1,1,""S1P" & i & """)")
        YVal = ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.CHART.ITEM(2,1,""S1P" & i & """)")

        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Points(1).DataLabel
            .Left = XVal - 550
            .Top = YVal + 50
        End With

        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Points(2).DataLabel
            .Left = XVal - 500
            .Top = YVal + 50
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop through both data series you could simply add a loop:

```
Public Sub ChangeCoordinates()
    Dim cht As Chartobject
    Dim srs As Excel.Series

    Dim h as Long
    Dim i As Long


    Set cht = Application.ActiveChart

    For h = 3 to 5 step 2

        Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(h)

        For i = 1 To srs.Points.Count
            XVal = ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.CHART.ITEM(1,1,""S1P" & i & """)")
            YVal = ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.CHART.ITEM(2,1,""S1P" & i & """)")

            With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(h).Points(i).DataLabel 'replaced points(1) with points(i)
                .Left = XVal - 550
                .Top = YVal + 50
            End With

        Next i
    Next h
End Sub
```

To also loop through all your worksheets, and charts on those worksheets you just add more loops :)

```
Public Sub ChangeCoordinates()
    Dim cht As chartobject
    Dim srs As Excel.Series
    Dim shtcount as Long
    Dim chtcount as Long
    Dim f as long
    Dim g as Long
    Dim h as Long
    Dim i As Long

    shtcount = thisworkbook.worksheets.count

    For f = 1 to shtcount
        chtcount = thisworkbook.worksheets(f).chartobjects.count
        For g = 1 to chtcount
            Set cht = thisworkbook.worksheets(f).ChartObjects(g)

                For h = 3 to 5 step 2

                    Set srs = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(h)

                    For i = 1 To srs.Points.Count

                        XVal = ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.CHART.ITEM(1,1,""S1P" & i & """)")
                        YVal = ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.CHART.ITEM(2,1,""S1P" & i & """)")

                        With srs.Points(i).DataLabel 'replaced points(1) with points(i)
                            If h = 3 Then
                                .Left = XVal - 550
                                .Top = YVal + 50
                            Else
                                'Insert other values for series 5 here
                            End if
                        End With

                    Next i
                Next h
        Next g
    Next f
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong - but I'm getting 13 - type mismatch.

Comment: On what line? Could very well be, I just wrote this from the top of my head, and didn't test it as I don't have sample data.

Comment: Seems at line 16 - Set cht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(f).ChartObjects(g)

Comment: I see, cht shouldnt be defined as excel.chart but as chartobject

Comment: Thankss for your help with this - getting 438 object doesn't support property or method on line 20 Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(h)

Comment: @tj123 I was missing a .Chart in this line: `Set srs = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(h)`

Comment: Thanks - the looping through all charts in the worksheet does work. It place the labels for the differnt dataseries over the top of each other - is there a way to name series 3 and 5 individually? Then I could specify different values for .Left = XVal and .Top = YVal

Comment: @tj123 I my answer was helpfull, feel free to select it as accepted answer and mark your question as resolved with that.

Comment: Yes that works thanks - is there any way to prevent me needing to click on a chart before running?

Comment: You won't need to click on a chart. There only should be charts present.

Comment: For some reason if I don't click on say the first chart in series before running I get 13 type mismatch - Do I need to put anything like Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() in the sheet?

Comment: Its on line 29 - .Left = XVal